# How to create multinode kubernetes clusters

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

All kubernetes instruction ask to work with minikube that gives you a single kubernetes host. What options are available to work with true multinode clusters. For example I have VM servers available to me. What tools I need to employ to spin up a few VMWare fusion machines on my Mac and create a Kubernetes cluster. Can I start a few machines in VirtualBox and use them as a Kubernetes Cluster.

Comment: Now that I understand Kubernetes much better, the right answer would have been to create a Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm will give you all the low level understanding of what goes into the master and worker nodes. Then you can choose to go with any of the higher level tools that make it much easier to work with kubenetes like kops, helmchart and every vendor has their own toolset to make creating a kubernetes cluster easier and automated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'minikube' is ideal for spinning up kubernetes on a single node. If you want to spin up kubernetes for multinode environment try 'kubeadm'

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/

Comment: Checkout `kube-spawn` (https://github.com/kinvolk/kube-spawn/). It can be used to support multi-node cluster on a single baremetal machine.

Answer (score 9):

I think that we need to clear up some definitions here.

First, what is Kubernetes:

> Kubernetes is a portable, extensible open-source platform for managing
>   containerized workloads and services, that facilitates both
>   declarative configuration and automation.
>
> Kubernetes has a number of features. It can be thought of as: a
>   container platform
>   -   a microservices platform
>   -   a portable cloud platform and a lot more.

You can read more about what is and what is not Kubernetes [here.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/)

Second, what is a minikube? Minikube is an all-in-one install of Kubernetes, as it takes all the [components](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/) of Kubernetes (Master Components, Node Components, potential Add-ons) and runs them in a single virtual machine.
You can install Kubernetes in many different ways as listed in this [documentation section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/), and if there is no minikube as you have asked, there still are many different ways to install minikube, for example, kubeadm as [Murli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1416534/murli) said, [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray), [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/), [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops), [Azure Kubernetes Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/), etc.

I highly recommend you to try [kelseyhightower](https://github.com/kelseyhightower)/[kubernetes-the-hard-way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way) as it will walk you through setting up the cluster manually which will give you a good understanding on how things work inside Kubernetes - you can do that in [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/) (there is 300$ free trial) or other platforms. There is also this **[guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/scratch/)** in Kubernetes documentation where you can run Kubernetes on physical device step by step:

> Note that it requires considerably more effort than using one of the
>   pre-defined guides.
>
> This guide is also useful for those wanting to understand at a high
>   level some of the steps that existing cluster setup scripts are
>   making.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using minikube only gives a wrong impression that you know kubernetes. There is a lot more moving parts when you try to deploy on a real platform.